# flex-justify content in raw of autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, autocomplete

[image]

I want to make space long space between name, username and email, this is my code in laravel blade file, javascript. This is autocomplete search, where is in raws some text, and I want to change how it looks. I have now space like `item.name+" "+item.surname`

This is code where is shown text in autocomplete

```
results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    text:item.firstname+' '+item.lastname+' '+' | '+' '+item.name+' '+' | '+' '+item.email,
                                    id: item.user_id,
                                    url: '/master/users/'+item.user_id,
                                }
                            })
```

Comment: results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    text:item.firstname+' '+item.lastname+' '+' | '+' '+item.name+' '+' | '+' '+item.email,
                                    id: item.user_id,
                                    url: '/master/users/'+item.user_id,
                                }
                            })

Comment: `justify-content` won't work on a string. You've to wrap the result with a tag e.g: `<span>item.firstname</span>`. Can you please provide a snippet of your code?